# Retrieve native length of hash from HMACSHA1 and HMACSHA512

Tags: c#, .net, sha, hmac, hmacsha1

I would like to get (programmatically) the native length of the HMAC function from an instance (or static method) of that class. (160 bits for SHA1, 512 for SHA512. AFAIK) Is there a way?

If not, perhaps there's a way to get it from SHA1Managed or SHA1 (and their SHA512 counterparts)?

Comment: Please add the C# tag or something similar and links to the various classes. I suppose that "security" is too generic and "hmacsha1" too specific so you could remove those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick search shows the [`HashAlgorithm.HashSize`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.hashalgorithm.hashsize(v=vs.110).aspx) property that those classes implement.

Comment: That's one small search for Maarten, one giant miss for me. I was searching all over for "output" this and that, and forgot about `HashSize`. Thanks.